# Why can't i see the events i send from my mobile google analytics?

Tags: android, google-analytics

Im using this code (which is the standard code from the examples):

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();

// Start the tracker in manual dispatch mode...
tracker.startNewSession("UA-36435865-1", 10, this);
tracker.setDebug(true);

// ...alternatively, the tracker can be started with a dispatch interval (in seconds).
//tracker.startNewSession("UA-YOUR-ACCOUNT-HERE", 20, this);

setContentView(R.layout.main);
Button createEventButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.NewEventButton);
createEventButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    tracker.trackEvent(
        "Clicks",  // Category
        "Button",  // Action
        "clicked", // Label
        77);       // Value
  }
});

Button createPageButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.NewPageButton);
createPageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // Add a Custom Variable to this pageview, with name of "Medium" and value "MobileApp"
    tracker.setCustomVar(1, "Medium", "Mobile App");
    // Track a page view. This is probably the best way to track which parts of your application
    // are being used.
    // E.g.
    // tracker.trackPageView("/help"); to track someone looking at the help screen.
    // tracker.trackPageView("/level2"); to track someone reaching level 2 in a game.
    // tracker.trackPageView("/uploadScreen"); to track someone using an upload screen.
    tracker.trackPageView("/testApplicationHomeScreen");
  }
});

Button quitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.QuitButton);
quitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    finish();
  }
});

Button dispatchButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.DispatchButton);
dispatchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // Manually start a dispatch, not needed if the tracker was started with a dispatch
    // interval.
    tracker.dispatch();
  }
});
```

}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Stop the tracker when it is no longer needed.
    tracker.stopSession();
  }

When looking at the logcat, i see that it is transmitted ok.

What do you think is the problem?

Comment: Internet permission is set?`Any exceptions in the log file? The UA-number is definitely correct?

Comment: Yap,these are my permissions: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> (taken from the example).   In the logcat i see that the packets are sent (getting 200 http from google analytic log tag) and as for the UA number, this is the number from my google app: UA-36435865-1, and this is the number this is use. Very weird...

Answer (score 1):

After 3 days i found the solution.

When i was using the standard SDK examples from google there are using google analytics lib ver 1 (libGoogleAnalytics.jar), but when referring from google analytifcs web site, they say we should use ver 2 of the protocol (libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar). so i guess the examples in the sdk are not updated yet...

Anyway, not it is working very good.